# iOS bbc iPlayer style wheel

Tags: ios

Does anyone know how to create the wheel like the one used on BBC iPlayer to scroll/slide through the channels on screen?
like in the link below:
http://gogetcreative.co.uk/blog/ui/bbc-releases-radio-iplayer-website-and-app

Is it a gui element, a type of view, any ideas?

thank you

Comment: Hi O Daniel, i also have the same issue. Please update your answer if you have resolved this issue by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It is a "self  programmed view" with own drawRect method.
In drawRect you paint the circles yourself.

Answer (score 0):

By the timing of release i would guess they made use of the new `UICollectionView` with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. Check the WWDC 2012 videos about CollectionView and the advanced talk about that issue.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I will attempt to do it using UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something similar using [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)